# Падает производительность при использования предиката для гибкой сортировки в LINQ запросе

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressions

Пытаюсь сделать LINQ запрос в котором можно менять поле (одно) по которому нужно производить сортировку. Использование переменной предиката позволяет это

```
public void GetMyData(string sortFieldName)
{
    Func<MyEntity, object> orderPredicate = null;
    switch (sortFieldName)
    {    
         case "FIELD_STRING":
             orderPredicate = x => x.FIELD_STRING;
         case "FIELD_INT":
             orderPredicate = x => x.FIELD_INT;
         case "FIELD_DATE":
             orderPredicate = x => x.FIELD_DATE;
         default: 
             orderPredicate = x => x.FIELD_DATE;
    }

    var queryResult = db.MyEntity.OrderBy(orderPredicate);

    //...some logic

}
```

Но резко (в десятки раз) падает производительность по сравнению с прямым заданием условия сортировки.
Насколько понимаю, должно помочь Expression. Меняю тип переменной

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> orderPredicate = null;
```

Но в рантайме выдаёт исключение

> Не удалось привести тип "System.DateTime" к типу "System.Object". LINQ to Entities поддерживает только приведение типов-примитивов моделей EDM или типов перечисления.

Как же быть? Ведь, если я буду использовать прямое задание условия

```
public void GetMyData(string sortFieldName)
{
    var query = db.MyEntity;
    var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_DATE);
    switch (sortFieldName)
    {    
         case "FIELD_STRING":
             orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_STRING); break;
         case "FIELD_INT":
             orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_INT); break;
         case "FIELD_DATE":
             orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_DATE); break;
    }

    //...some logic

}
```

, мне будет трудно усложнить запрос дополнительными инструкциями `Where`, `Include` и т.д.

Comment: А если как-то так написать: https://pastebin.com/53quNm76

Comment: @Андрей, ну так про то и пишу, что так (прямое задание сортировки) работает быстро, а с переменной предиката много медленней.

Comment: Естественно будет медленнее, так при использовании `IEnumerable` сортировка будет происходить на клиенте

Comment: @Андрей, какое-нибудь компромиссное решение, между гибкостью и производительностью можно найти?

Comment: Кстати на Expression пока проблема только с DateTime полями, остальные значит приводятся.

Comment: Ну а чем мой способ-то не устраивает?

Comment: @Андрей, Мне кажется, так будет сложней реализовать более сложные запросы c `Where`, `Include` и т.д.

Comment: Никакого усложнения по сравнению с вашим способом нет. Просто берете `orderedQuery` и докручиваете на него свои любые `Where` и `Include`: `orderedQuery.Where(x => x.IntProp == 1)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда вы пишите вот так:

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> orderPredicate;
orderPredicate = x => x.FIELD_DATE;
```

Компилятор делает вот так:

```
var _param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "x");
orderPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, object>>(
    Expression.Convert(
        Expression.Property(_param, "FIELD_DATE"),
        typeof(object)
    ),
    _param
);
```

Вот на этот самый `Expression.Convert` EF и ругается. Для того чтобы не было преобразования - возвращаемый тип делегата обязан совпадать с типом свойства, что в свою очередь означает что общую переменную `orderPredicate` вы использовать не можете.

---

Теперь как строить такие запросы. А строятся они очень просто - через накопление `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> q = db.MyEntity;
switch (sortFieldName)
{    
     case "FIELD_STRING":
         q = q.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_STRING);
     case "FIELD_INT":
         q = q.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_INT);
     case "FIELD_DATE":
         q = q.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_DATE);
     default:
         q = q.OrderBy(x => x.FIELD_DATE);
}
```

Никакого усложнения тут нет, полученный запрос можно точно также дополнять другими условиями:

```
q = q.Where(x => x.Foo > 42);
```

---

PS поскольку у вас в параметре `sortFieldName` передается имя свойства, построение выражения можно еще немного упростить. Да, класс `Queryable` не дает нам вызвать `OrderBy` с неизвестным заранее именем свойства - но никто не мешает "раскрыть" этот метод и работать непосредственно с `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> q = db.MyEntity;

var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity));
var propExpr = Expression.Property(entityParam, sortFieldName)
q = q.Provider.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(
    Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", 
        new [] { entityParam.Type, propExpr.Type }, // Типы-параметры для метода Queryable.OrderBy<,>
        q.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(propExpr, entityParam))
    )
);
```

Также вместо того чтобы делать это вручную - можно использовать библиотеку `System.Linq.Dynamic`, скачав ее из nuget:

```
q = q.OrderBy(sortFieldName);
```

Comment: А если типизация будет корректной, то конвертации не будет?

Comment: @Monk да, не будет